# Can't delete series with binary tag

Tags: influxql

I accidentally inserted a tag with some single quotes in them in a series:

```
> show series
key
---
sensor,boardid=b'5ddd2d00'
sensor,boardid=living_room
```

and I can't get rid of them. I've tried

```
drop series from sensor where boardid="b\'5ddd2d00\'"
drop series from sensor where boardid="b'5ddd2d00'"
drop series from sensor where boardid='5ddd2d00'
```

but the series is still there.

*how to remove it* ??

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but don't like it, via a regex

```
drop series  where boardid =~  /5ddd2d00/
```